# Segmentation fault while sorting strings in C (qsort)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, qsort

Here is my code. I am using a Message Queue to send a list of names to another process. This process receives the correct set of names without any problems, but the sorting part keeps segfaulting.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/msg.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<string.h>

#define KEY 1000
#define MAX 100
#define MSG_TYPE1 1
#define MSG_TYPE2 2

typedef struct names{
    long int type;
    char names[MAX][MAX];
}msg_name;

int cmp(const void* s1, const void* s2){return strcmp(*(char* const*)s1, *(char* const*)s2);}

int main(){
    int id=msgget(KEY, 0666);
    msg_name m1;
    m1.type = MSG_TYPE1;

    int n,i;

    int sz = msgrcv(id, (void*)&m1, sizeof(m1.names), MSG_TYPE1, 0);
    n=sz/MAX;
    printf("%d names received\n", n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){printf("%s\n", m1.names[i]);}

    qsort(m1.names, n, sizeof(m1.names), cmp);

    printf("The sorted list of names:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){printf("%s\n", m1.names[i]);}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `qsort(m1.names, n, sizeof(m1.names), cmp);` -> `qsort(m1.names, n, sizeof(m1.names[0]), cmp);`

Comment: @PaulR, still the same thing. :/

Comment: Time to learn how to use your debugger then...

Comment: Can you provide me a good resource on doing that?

Comment: There are several other bugs, but the most serious one is that the parameters you are passing to strcmp are incorrect.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @PaulR, thanks for the link. I changed the strcmp parameters to `strcmp(s1,s2)`, and it worked. I found the previous code in the man page of the `qsort` function. I don't understand what's wrong with it.

What other bugs are there?

Comment: Hint: Look at the parameters you are passing to msgrcv.

Comment: is it wrong to pass `sizeof(m1.names)`?

Comment: No, it’s the second parameter that is wrong - you should be passing m1.names, not m1.

Comment: I don't think so.
The man page of msgrcv says:
The msgp argument is a pointer to a  caller-defined  structure  of  the
       following general form:

           `struct msgbuf {
               long mtype;       /* message type, must be > 0 */
               char mtext[1];    /* message data */
           };`

Comment: Ah OK - my bad then. The only other bugs I see are that you have no error checking on calls that may fail.

Comment: Yeah, that's right.
Also, can you please explain why changing removing `*(char* const *)` worked? (despite it being in the man page of qsort)?

Comment: You are comparing strings, so you don’t need the cast, and the de-reference is just plain wrong.